# Reorder comma separated values

Tags: php, csv

I have a list of comma separated numerical values. This string will only have list of numbers.

Example: 52,187,65,278,288,45,621

I want a php function which will reformat the string such that I can specify the location of a number.

If I want 45 as the first value then I should be able to specify 45 = 0 then the function will provide me a result which is 45,52,187,65,278,288,621

The function should also help me specify location of multiple numbers.

Comment: I usually get 5 downvotes for such a question... Please provide your work so far.

Comment: and if you specify 278 = 335 what should happen? or 65 = 2.

Comment: You could make an array with this values with explode(), order it, and implode() again

Comment: ^ There's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is by using `explode()` on the string to create an array and `array_search()` to find the value. Might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

first you would want to generate an array of the string by exploding it with the commas `$arr = explode(",",$string);` you then want to match the options and set the place in the array, try searching with `array_search` to get the index, pull it out with `array_splice` then insert in the correct index as specified.
After you have done all of your sorting join the array back together with implode: `$string = implode(",", $arr);`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$str='52,187,65,278,288,45,621';
$val ='45';
$array = array();
$array = explode(',',$str);
sort($array);
$i=0;
foreach ($array as $k) {

    if ($k<$val){
        unset ($array[$i]);
    }

    $i=$i+1;    
}
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is long code

```
<?php
$str = '52,187,65,278,288,45,621';
$orders =  array(45 => 3,52=>2);

print_r(reOrder($str,$orders));

function reOrder($string,$orders){
    $array = explode(',', $string);
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $index=>$element){
        if(isset($orders[$element])){
            if(!isset($result[$orders[$element]] )){
                $result[$orders[$element]] = $element;
            }
            else{
                $temp = $result[$orders[$element]];
                $result[$orders[$element]] = $element;
                $count = count($result);
                $flag = 0;
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                    if(!isset($result[$i])){
                        $result[$i] = $temp;
                        $flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($flag == 0){
                    $result[] = $temp;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $count = count($result);
            $flag = 0;
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
                if(!isset($result[$i])){
                    $result[$i] = $element;
                    $flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($flag == 0){
                $result[] = $element;
            }
        }
    }
    ksort($result);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this three steps

```
<?php
$myArray = explode(",", $myString);
$shortedArray = sort($myArray);
$shortedString = implode(",", $shortedArray);
echo $shortedString;
?>
```